Type inference of Zod object keys in custom function
I'm making a function called createDefinition that takes a Zod object as its argument, using ZodType to narrow the allowed Zod shapes that can be passed to it (in this case, JSON only).
However, because this function always takes a z.object() and will be called many times, it would be nice to just take the inner properties of the passed object as the argument to avoid having to type out z.object() every time you want to call createDefinition — which will call z.object({ ...passedProps }) inside of itself for convenience.
I'm struggling to type my function inputs (see version 2 below) in a way that creates a type-compatible Zod object.
Version one (works, but requires z.object() to be passed to it):
type Result<S extends JsonObject> = {
  _schema: ZodType<S>;
};

export const createDefinition = <Shape extends JsonObject>(
  schema: z.ZodType<Shape>,
): Result<Shape> => {
  // ... Do stuff
  return {
    _schema: schema,
  };
};

createDefinition(z.object({
  string: z.string(),
  date: z.date(), // TypeError -> as expected
}));

Version two (convenience version), does not work:
type Result<S extends JsonObject> = {
  _schema: ZodType<S>;
};

export const createDefinition = <Shape extends JsonObject>(
  schemaProperties: {
    [K in keyof Shape]: z.ZodType<Shape[K]>,
  }
): Result<Shape> => {
  const schema = z.object(schemaProperties);
  // ... Do stuff
  return {
    _schema: schema, // Type error :: `schema` doesn't match ZodType<Shape>
  };
};

createDefinition({
  string: z.string(),
  date: z.date(), // No TypeError?
});

